# Нужны ли кавычки во фразе "план Б"?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Имеется фраза "переходим к плану Б". Нужно ли заключать в кавычки букву "б"? И какой она должна быть: прописной или строчной?

Сама фраза подразумевает переход к запасному варианту, т. е. здесь используется идиома.

К сожалению, поиск в этом комьюнити по слову "кавычки" результатов не дал. Есть ли какой-нибудь авторитетный источник, дающий исчерпывающий ответ на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По [этой](http://pda.gramota.ru/?action=buro&s=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B1) ссылке Грамота уже ответила на этот вопрос, что правильно писать так: ***план Б***, то есть *без кавычек и с большой буквы.* Кстати, прежде чем найти этот её ответ, я предположил именно такое написание. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, +1. К сожалению, Грамота не обосновывает свой ответ... А, например, в [газетном корпусе](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EB%E0%ED%20%E1&mode=paper) встречается различное написание. Однако судя по тому, что в корпусе часто закавычивают **фразу целиком** (*"план Б"*, по аналогии с англ. *Plan B*), по мере "натурализации" этого выражения кавычки, видимо, просто отбрасываются.

Comment: Грамота вообще не особо утруждает себя пояснениями. Особенно последнее время. Тем не менее её ответ стоит признать правильным.

Answer (score 1):

Грамота права. Попробую обосновать.
То, что это идиома, говорит лишь о необязательности **внешних** кавычек, хотя и они не будут ошибкой, если представление о читающем не предполагает априорное знание им предмета.

В остальном же придерживаться стоит общих представлений. Б - условное обозначение, условное имя собственное, поэтому буква нужна заглавная, а кавычки (для самой буквы) не нужны.

Comment: Я согласен про внешние кавычки. Поискав в корпусе, понял, что идиома пришла из английского. Возможность внешних кавычек, как я понимаю, исключает кавычки для буквы "Б". Только не совсем понятно, почему вы, признавая ответ Грамоты верным, пишете, что заглавная для "Б" не нужна.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, behemothus относит "не нужны" только к кавычкам, т. е. надо читать со смыслом "поэтому буква *должна быть* заглавной и кавычки не нужны".

Comment: А, понял. Спасибо, Артем.

Comment: Не за что, A. P.))

Comment: Да виноват, несколько двусмысленно фраза прозвучала, не подумал. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Сугубое имхо.

Эта проблема находится несколько на периферии грамматики... Проще говоря, это не так уж интересно. Логичнее и экономичнее писать без кавычек, но и кавычки не будут грубой ошибкой.

А как здесь можно *обосновать ответ*?!

Comment: Ну есть же какие-то рекомендации наверняка.